# How to implement a client server where they both communicate independently

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to implement a client server system in java using sockets. Before I start coding I want to do a bit of planning, but I am slightly confused about how to implement the following system. I have some, but little knowledge of Sockets and ServerSockets in java.

The client will be constantly sending data to the server about the current status of the client, the server only logs this (to display to the user).

The server will issue commands to the client based on input from the user.

Therefor both the client and the server will need to be listening and sending data simultaneously. For this will I need a Socket (to send data) and a ServerSocket (to listen for data) to be open on both devices, with each running in separate threads?

If this is the case, will I have to use two different ports or can I use the same one?

Answer (score 0):

The server uses **one** `ServerSocket` to wait for new clients. Each client gets it's own `Socket` with Input- and Outputstream. I would use one Thread for the ServerSocket and one per client to listen to the incoming messages.

Comment: The client has it's side of the Socket. The only one owning a port is the listening ServerSocket of the server, so you don't need multiple ports.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a ServerSocket on the server.  This listens for connections from clients.  Each client uses a regular Socket to connect to the server.  For each client that connects, the server will get a regular Socket from its ServerSocket using the ServerSocket.accept() method.  The ServerSocket listens only on a single port; all clients connect to this same server port.

At each endpoint of each connection, only a single Socket is needed.  You will get an OutputStream from the Socket.getOutputStream() method to send data, and an InputStream from the Socket.getInputStream() method to send data on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This will form peer-to-peer architecture, which states one node will be acting as both server and client depending on situation.

Secondly, you will write both server and client code on both nodes. One port will be used as port is captured on server not on client and on one node you have only one server deployed so one port will be fine.